# Not able to get Userinfo from google api in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api, google-plus-signin

I am making a simple app in Ruby I need to get User's Email. I am using Google API client for Ruby. I am not able to get User's Email address, I have been researching on this topic for 2 days, and not able to get Email of user after the user sign in. I dont want to do it with Google+ sign in button I want it programmatically. I get authorized by google but then dont know how to retrieve the User Info of signed in user. I tried also tried it with `client = Google::APIClient.new` but i was not able. Below is my Code. I will appreciate your help.

```
scopes =  ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email']
  client_secrets = Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets.load(SECRETS_PATH)
  auth_client = client_secrets.to_authorization
  auth_client.update!(
      :additional_parameters => {"access_type" => "offline"}
  )
  auth_client.update!(
      :scope => scopes,
      :redirect_uri => 'http://localhost:3000/google_oauth2')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey On this You can Refer the Gem [Google Plus](https://github.com/seejohnrun/google_plus)

I have implemented the same and It's Working Fine from these sides.

Steps to Integrate Following Gem-

1. Firstly Install the google_plus gem by including it on GemFile.
2. Generate the API Key from Google Console of Google Plus +

   https://console.developers.google.com
3. Including it Before use like it

   ```
   GooglePlus.api_key = 'your key'
   ```
4. Search any Person by Id of Google

   ```
   person = GooglePlus::Person.get(123)
   ```

You will get the complete users info for particular users

Comment: If you need help on this just comment here

Comment: Google+ is old now and should not be used. Is there any other way?